# Displayed Text in column is not displaying in the correct location of the cell

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

In my first column of my table, the displayed value is offset from the left edge.

Example

[image]

Notice the offset of the date value compared to the ItemId value

```
TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(125);
  col.getColumn().setText("Date Created");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
       AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData p = (AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData) element;
      return p.getDateTime();
    }
  });

  col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(100);
  col.getColumn().setText("ItemId");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
       AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData p = (AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData) element;
      return p.getItemId();
    }
  });
```

Looking at the code above I do not see why they would be a difference?

Comment: Are you sure, that the date you get via `getDateTime()` doesn't have extra spaces at the beginning? Your other code looks correct.

Comment: Yes - I also used the same element p.getItemId() as in column two and it still had the space.

Comment: Does any of your columns display an image?

Comment: Sorry, but you are right it is a image not a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the very annoying SWT bugs when using windows. [Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=43910) is the bug report. In windows, if the table contains an image which is not in the first column, the first column will show this "gap".

You can use a dirty fix by skipping the first column (not using it) and setting its width to zero.

As far as I remember correctly, this will introduce some minor glitches when using MacOS.

---

There is a very hacky work-around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644234/1449199) as well.